# power spectral density scaling factor frequency bin width

Tags: fft

How to choose scaling factor for calculating PSD? Because I saw `abs(fft)^2` scaled by `fs/N` (frequency binwidth) and also `1/fs*N`. obviously output amplitude values will be different. So I want to know which scaling factor will choose? or in which situation each scaling factor will take?

I am showing matlab program from google here.

N = length(x);
xdft = fft(x);
xdft = xdft(1:N/2+1);
psdx = (1/(Fs*N)) * abs(xdft).^2;
psdx(2:end-1) = 2*psdx(2:end-1);
freq = 0:Fs/length(x):Fs/2;

plot(freq,10*log10(psdx))
grid on
title('Periodogram Using FFT')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Power/Frequency (dB/Hz)')

psdx = (1/(Fs*N)) * abs(xdft).^2; this is scaling the amplitude of signal
instead of that I did

bin=Fs/NFFT;
B=F.*conj(F)/bin; %% F=fftshift( abs(fft(ampli,NFFT)));
is this correct for psd calculation ?

Comment: That is just a repetition of your last question and does not specify what's not answering your question in the answer you've already gotten.

Comment: adding someone else's matlab program does not clarify your own question.